# How to get 2 digit after the decimal point with number type

Tags: java

I have a number as`number a= 2.944127983333377` Now I want to formatted it as `2.94`.
I searched and I found `new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(a)`
But the problem that it's type is string and not number.

Comment: So convert the number to a string.

Comment: Use proper terminology or if you don't know the proper terms, describe your problem *thoroughly*. Formatting *implies* output, not altering a numbers value. Rounding on the other hand deals with altering values.

Comment: I don't found a way to convert string to number. I had found only int , string double long and float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
double value= 2.944127983333377;
// Multiply it by 100, convert the result into an integer to trim
// remaining decimals then divide it by 100d to get the result as double
double result = (int)(value * 100) / 100d;
System.out.println(result);
```

**Output:**

```
2.94
```

If you want a `Number`, simply replace the type `double` of `result` with `Number`, thanks to autoboxing it will convert automatically the `double` into a `Double` which is a sub class of `Number`:

```
Number result = (int)(value * 100) / 100d;
```

Comment: I want number type as output and not double

Comment: a Double is a Number actually, I don' understand what you expect

Comment: Because I'm using a method that accept a number type if i insert a double variable it show me an error

Comment: I've updated my answer, check again

Comment: It work with double type thanks

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/Precision.html#round(float,%20int,%20int)

```
double z = Precision.round(2.944127983333377, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
```